# Меню при открытии тормозит

Tags: java, android

Есть Активити которая содержит в себе карту кнопки и боковое меню.Так вот при открытии Бокового меню анимация слегка тормозит.Не сильно но всеравно досаден сам факт.Но в простом приложении без карты тормозов нету.Как быть ?ктото сталкивался?вот разметка xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myDrawer"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="zyklen.com.clientcoord.MapsActivity">

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

        <include
            layout="@layout/floating_menu"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/navik"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:itemTextColor="#383636"
        app:itemIconTint="#131313"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header">

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>




</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: @SviatVolkov на сколько я знаю карта по умолчанию грузится асинх

Comment: DrawerLayout с фрагментом внутри почти 100% всегда тормозит.

Comment: Может даже тормозить из за того, что иконки по размеру будут большими в Navigation. или если вы в манифесте поставили         android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: @androidx  android:largeHeap="true"  стоит и да иконки тоже большие и как быть ?(

Comment: https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html
поставь размеры иконок. картинок и т.д. в соответствии с Material Design см. ссылку.
и если поставил  android:largeHeap="true" только для этого, то поправьте все и  удалите эту строку с манифеста, а если все таки у вас будет вылетать OutOfMemoryException, то нужно найти другие способы для решения, android:largeHeap="true", это не хорошее решение, все равно в один момент опять будет вылетать эта ошибка

Comment: @androidx кидает ошибку пойду покапаю